# How to approximate this function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, approximation

I have a function in the following form:

$a^k+b^k+c^k=1$,

where $0<a,b,c<1$, and k is the unknown. I need to solve this equation for $k$ a ~million times for different $a$, $b$ and $c$ values. Although it works appropriately with an iterative approximation, it would take ages to finish.

I wonder if this function could be approximated with an infinite series. Can you give me any suggestions I can follow to find such an approximation?

Comment: there is this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2778053/399263, but no definitive answer I fear.

Comment: Because you're region of a, b, and c is very restricted, it seems newtons method maybe converge from a simple guess pretty well in maybe 10 or 20 iterations. You might just try newtons method with some rather hardcore iteration limiting, at least as a baseline. Especially, since your input is a cube, you could precompute with Newtons method at regular intervals and then save that and try some sort of interpolation

Comment: @CadeReinberger This would be an efficient method for most of the points inside the cube. However, k tends to infinity close to the faces of the cube making the interpolation very inaccurate in those regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the zero of function $$f(k)=a^k+b^k+c^k-1$$  For sure, a numerical method should be used.

Making the function more linear, consider instead you look for the zero of the more linear function
$$g(k)=\log(a^k+b^k+c^k)$$ for which
$$g'(k)=\frac{a^k \log (a)+b^k \log (b)+c^k \log (c)}{a^k+b^k+c^k}\quad < 0 \quad \forall k$$
$$g''(k)=\frac{a^k b^k
   (\log (a)-\log (b))^2+a^kc^k \left( \log (a)-\log (c))^2+b^kc^k (\log (b)-\log (c))^2\right)}{\left(a^k+b^k+c^k\right)^2}$$ wich is positive $\forall k$.

Since $g(0)=\log(3) >0$, by Darboux theorem, the first iterate of Newton method is an underestimate of the solution. So, using $k_0=0$
$$k_1=-\frac {3\log(3)}{\log(abc)}$$ could be "reasonable".

Trying for $a=\frac 12$, $b=\frac 13$, $c=\frac 14$, this would give $$k_1=\frac{\log (27)}{\log (24)}\approx 1.03706$$ while the exact solution is $1.08213$.

Performing the next iterations according to
$$k_{n+1}=k_n-\frac{g(k_n)}{g'(k_n)}=k_n -\frac{\left(a^{k_n}+b^{k_n}+c^{k_n}\right) \log \left(a^{k_n}+b^{k_n}+c^{k_n}\right)}{a^{k_n} \log (a)+b^{k_n}
   \log (b)+c^{k_n} \log (c)}$$ For the worked example, the would give $k_2=1.08205$ and a second iteration leads to the solution.

**Edit**

You could have a better estimate of the solution computing the first iterate of the original Halley method and get

$$k_1=\frac{3 \log (3) \log (abc)} {(\log (3)-1) A-(2+\log (3))B }$$ where
$$A=\log ^2(a)+\log ^2(b)+\log ^2(c)$$
$$B=\log (a) \log (b)+\log (a) \log (c)+\log (b) \log (c)$$

For the worked example, this would give $k_1=1.07979$ which is much better.

Comment: This is a valuable answer. What I do not understand is how the second equation is equivalent to the first one.

Comment: The roots of $f(k)=1$ are the same as the roots of $g(k)=\log(f(k))=0$